# ArgumentError: You need to supply at least one validation with :if

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a simple model

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :deadline, :if => :deadline_in_future?

  def deadline_in_future?
    Date.today < self.deadline
  end
end
```

All seems ok, but when I in my rails console

```
irb(main):001:0> Task.new
ArgumentError: You need to supply at least one validation
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You forgot to tell `validates` how you want to validate `:deadline`. I think you're misunderstanding what `:if` does; the `:if => :deadline_in_future?` option means:

> Validate `:deadline` only if the `deadline_in_future?` method returns a true value.

I suspect that you want to validate that the deadline is in the future:

```
validate :deadline_in_future?
```

Further details are available in the [Active Record Validations and Callbacks Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods).

Answer (score 130):

You must change `validates` to `validate`.

Comment: @yeyo Because it's a syntax for custom validation. See [Custom Methods in Active Record Validations Doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods)

Answer (score 3):

It says you do not pass any validations to `validates` method. Like `validates :presence`, for example. What are you trying to validate?

Comment: I'm trying to do validation like this one http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless

Comment: In that example `:presence => true` says that presence of `card_number` field should be validated but validation should be performed only if `paid_with_card?` method returns true. The idea behind that is that order should have credit number if payment was made via credit card, but if payment was made not with credit card there's no need to check that card number is properly stored.